# why doesn't message signed with openssl_pkcs7_sign validate with openssl_pkcs7_verify?

Tags: php, openssl, pkcs#7, php-openssl

The signing code is based off of the example at http://php.net/openssl-pkcs7-sign. The private key corresponds to the public key in the cert. The cert is valid from one year ago to Dec 31, 9999, so the date range isn't an issue.

Does the key usage extension need to be set? And if that is the issue then to what does it need to be set? And if that's not the case then what exactly do I need to be doing to get this to work?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$data = <<<EOD

You have my authorization to spend $10,000 on dinner expenses.

The CEO
EOD;
// save message to file
$fp = fopen("msg.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

$key = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

$cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBwzCCASygAwIBAgIUP7VZQpJYe8YHW4Fdd+FaukIezEcwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEF
BQAwHjEcMBoGA1UECgwTcGhwc2VjbGliIGRlbW8gY2VydDAeFw0xNTA4MDExNjA3
NDNaFw0xNjA4MDExNjA3NDNaMB4xHDAaBgNVBAoME3BocHNlY2xpYiBkZW1vIGNl
cnQwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBALMlXVnRQpcuSX1OuG5FH2d2
1/5SkvLF25Z98WINeyu6iN3sHoBcB2yfJMf798OkENgGanCcdGSHZHQ5D/S2k3pK
EVxkO4Esyg26o/dWElmfTVuOl6pM7c2nzNhIdSsZwy/6H9/8cbWjyQqd1ZsBCvOP
QNQ6ufQOLffqZQuxwX+DAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEArmQMGP2XPQTI
b0ppXGTlAqLGx979GDYeWglCLSlUYw3Ohr3Jonhs7KnhX04Y3ePVqIKuqSDvZz/D
C3Xgaiqmq0OsHtro7O0BamauKANON6bwq/YthrbeNBUoy7XZ86WsRZGSPlts7jdQ
tiqqWvr+oWxNb8WkxqVCshifjSOTlOQ=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----';


// encrypt it
openssl_pkcs7_sign(
    'msg.txt',
    'signed.txt',
    $cert,
    $key,
    array(
        'To' => 'joes@example.com',  // keyed syntax
        'From: HQ <ceo@example.com>',// indexed syntax
        'Subject" => "Eyes only'
    )
);

echo file_get_contents('signed.txt');

var_dump(openssl_pkcs7_verify('signed.txt', 0));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. You have a self-signed certificate. In your case you should use

```
openssl_pkcs7_verify('signed.txt', PKCS7_NOVERIFY)
```

Then a self-signed certificate is acceptable.